# using jq to dynamically build json for use with github-actions strategy matrix

Tags: json, matrix, dynamic, github-actions, jq

I have a number of variables required for use with AWS and GitHub Actions.
The source is not JSON, but a terraform.tfvars file stored as a secret, but it needs to be dynamically converted at runtime into AWS CLI v2 --parameters and --parameter-overrides JSON for use with cloudformation.

example of variables in secret value PARAMS (stored as base64 to preserve LF):

```
unique_prefix = "a-unique-value"
base_region   = "ap-southeast-2"
```

The variables are also used outside CloudFormation calls (eg base_region is used in assume roles) so GitHub Actions needs a Matrix with its JSON format built also

I want these variables to be dynamically generated into various JSON formats with GitHub actions ideally with pure jq, and with minimal bash string manipulations into the inconsistent formats needed for AWS CLI CloudFormation commands, and GitHub action Matrix.

So a GitHub matrix with the following JSON input/output

```
{
  "include": [
    {
      "unique_prefix": "a-unique-value",
      "base_region": "ap-southeast-2",
    }
  ]
}
```

with a github job that reference this build-matrix job, can produce two variables that can be referenced with

```
          echo ${{ matrix.unique_prefix }}
          echo ${{ matrix.base_region }}
```

so using this strategy matrix, it should be possible to build the CloudFormation formats:

for input for a cloudformation Stack (--parameter-overrides file://param.json), the  result would be:

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "unique_prefix",
    "ParameterValue": "a-unique-value"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "base_region",
    "ParameterValue": "ap-southeast-2"
  }
]
```

for CloudFormation StackSets (--parameters), the result would be:

```
[
  {
    "Key": "unique_prefix",
    "Value": "a-unique-value"
  },
  {
    "Key": "base_region",
    "Value": "ap-southeast-2"
  }
]
```

So ideally, I would need a github action job that just creates these two or three JSON formats dynamically for further use in other jobs, or just the strategy matrix, and just convert that in further jobs., but i cant work out how to dynamically grab the input

currently im at this point of building a GitHub strategy matrix (and checked with debug)

```
name: Test
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-matrix:
    name: Build JSON from PARAMS
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - name: Create Mapping JSON
        id: set-matrix
        run: |
          echo '${{ secrets.PARAMS }}' | base64 --decode > "${{ github.workspace }}/terraform.fvars"
          # I dont know how to pull in the file here for jq
          JSON=$(jq -c -n --argjson v '{"unique_prefix":"a-unique-value","base_region":"ap-southeast-2"}' '{"include": [$v]}')
          echo "::set-output name=matrix::${JSON}"
```

and a debug job i use to show the yaml output of the matrix:

```
  check-matrix:
    name: Check Parameters
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build-matrix
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.build-matrix.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:
      - name: Install json2yaml
        run: |
          sudo npm install -g json2yaml

      - name: Check matrix definition
        run: |
          matrix='${{ needs.build-matrix.outputs.matrix }}'
          echo $matrix
          echo $matrix | jq .
          echo $matrix | json2yaml
          echo ${{ matrix.unique_prefix }} # Will show a-unique-value
          echo ${{ matrix.base_region }}   # Will show ap-southeast-2
          # jq to create CFN stacksets json params
          # jq to create CFN stack json params
```

so dynamically build the matrix from the terraform.tfvars file
and dynamically build the CFN JSON formats from either the matrix or similar method.

Comment: What exactly is the question? I think this post could focus on the specfics and remove some of the context, without hurting the question. What is your input, what is your expected output? Is the question how to process a file with `jq` (as written in the code block)? That's simply `jq 'program' path/to/file` or by redirecting IO